# Why am I bouncing between routes in backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

So I have a routes file:

```
Nightbird.Routers.Posts = Nightbird.Routers.Core.extend({

  DEFAULT_TIMEOUT: 15000,

  fetchPostsTimeout: null,

  routes: {
    'posts': 'posts',
    'post/:id': 'post',
  },

  posts: function() {
    var postsCollection = new Nightbird.Collections.Posts();
    postsCollection.fetch().then(this.postsRecieved, this.serverError);

    var self = this;
    this.fetchPostsTimeout = setInterval(function() {
      postsCollection.fetch().then(self.postsRecieved, self.serverError);
    }, this.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
  },

  post: function(id) {
    var postsCollection = new Nightbird.Collections.Posts({id: id});
    postsCollection.fetch().then(this.postRecieved.bind(this), self.serverError);
  },

  postsRecieved: function(collection, response, options) {
    var managementPostsView = new Nightbird.Views.ManagementPosts();
    managementPostsView.render(collection, this.currentPage);
  },

  postRecieved: function(collection, response, options) {
    new Nightbird.Views.ManagementPost(collection);
  },

})
```

All were doing here is defining  what happens when you visit said routes. So if you visit the `#posts` route, you'll get a list of posts and every 15 seconds we check for new posts.

But lets say you go to `#posts` then click on a post and are taken to `#post/x` where x is the post id. Lets look at the view for a single post.

```
Nightbird.Views.ManagementPost = Nightbird.Views.Core.extend({

  comments: {},

  post: {},

  commentsTimeOut: null,

  errorMessage: '',

  initialize: function(postsObject) {
    this.post = postsObject;
    var postId = this.post.post.id

    var commentsCollection = new Nightbird.Collections.Comments(postId);
    commentsCollection.fetch().then(this.getComments.bind(this), this.errorMessage.bind(this));

    var self = this;
    this.commentsTimeOut = setInterval(function() {
      commentsCollection.fetch().then(self.getComments.bind(self), self.errorMessage.bind(self));
    }, 15000);
  },

  getComments: function(collection, response, options) {
    this.comments = collection;
    this.render()
  },

  errorMessage: function() {
    this.errorMessage = 'We could not retrieve comments for the post. We will try again in 15 seconds.';
  },


  render: function(collection) {
    React.renderComponent(new ManagementPost({
      post: this.post,
      comments: this.comments,
      errorMessage: this.errorMessage
    }), this.getBlogManagementElement()[0])
  }

});
```

pretty simple, we get the comments for this post and then render the post. How ever note that here we check every 15 seconds for new comments and display them. We use react to render the finished product.

So whats the issue?

If you are on `#posts` and click on a blog title and are taken to `#posts/x` you will see a post with comments, awesome. But after 15 seconds we flash back to the list of posts, then 15 seconds later back to the post with comments. It does this every 15 seconds. It does not stop doing this "in between" until you refresh the page on the single post page, only then does it stop flashing back and forth.

Whats causing this? Is this because when you travel around in backbone via the router they are not true redirects? Should I be using backbones `Backbone.history.navigate('', {trigger:true})` and if so how do I pass things in like the ID? or other variables?

I am trying to build a "realtime" blog management system and this flickering issue is confusing me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setInterval returns a value. You need to hold on to this value and pass it to clearInterval when you want to stop it.  Backbone has no way of doing this for you automatically.

Comment: Does this mean that in the view for the post, where I am holding onto the value, I should be clearing it after I fetch the posts?